# Make pagination anywhere work on datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am working on datatables plugin (https://datatables.net/) and I am trying to make all custom elements work as datatable function.

Here is what I have done so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/moviecrew/fjcu9yLe/1/

```
var dataTable = $('#leadTable').DataTable({
 "columnDefs": [{
    "orderable": false,
    "targets": ['nosort']
  }]

});

dataTable.order([$('.default-sort').index(), 'asc']).draw();


var pageInfo,
  startRowCount,
  endRowCount,
  totalPagesCount,
  currentPagesCount,
  totalDisplayedRowCount,
  totalRowCount;



function pageInfoDisplay() {
  pageInfo = dataTable.page.info();

  startRowCount = pageInfo.start;
  endRowCount = pageInfo.end;
  totalPagesCount = pageInfo.pages;
  currentPagesCount = pageInfo.page;
  totalDisplayedRowCount = pageInfo.length;
  totalRowCount = pageInfo.recordsTotal;

  $('#leadTablePageInfo .current-rows').html(startRowCount + 1 + '-' + endRowCount);
  $('#leadTablePageInfo .total-rows').html(totalRowCount);
}

pageInfoDisplay();

$('#leadTableSearch').on('keyup', function() {
  dataTable.search(this.value).draw();
});

$('#leadTablePageLength').on('change', function() {
  dataTable.page.len(this.value).draw();
  pageInfoDisplay();

});

$('#leadTablePagination .page-next').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  dataTable.page('next').draw('page');

  pageInfoDisplay();

  if (currentPagesCount > 0) {
    $('#leadTablePagination .page-previous').parent().removeClass('disabled');
  }

  if (currentPagesCount + 1 == totalPagesCount) {
    $(this).parent().addClass('disabled');
  }

});

$('#leadTablePagination .page-previous').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  dataTable.page('previous').draw('page');

  pageInfoDisplay();

  if (currentPagesCount === 0) {
    $(this).parent().addClass('disabled');
  }

  if (currentPagesCount + 1 < totalPagesCount) {
    $('#leadTablePagination .page-next').parent().removeClass('disabled');
  }
});
```

Everything works perfectly. the only problem is with pagination. the previous and next button works fine, the only problem is with numbers. is there any way we can make this work?

Comment: For previous and next you have on click events - I don't see anything in your code for click events on the pagination numbers.

Comment: that's the problem. I couldn't find the way i can define numbers. I don't think numbers should have click events since it should be dynamic to the number of datas. isn't there any way that we can add numbers dynamically? @TerraElise

Comment: I mean, datatables already handles all that - unsure why you are redoing what exists, but you'd have to create the html yourself with javascript and attach click events.

Comment: @TerraElise i am redoing it only because it's outside of the datatable and can be anywhere in the page in other occurrence. so maybe it would have been easier if we could just use a class on the custom pagination and make it work using it's API

Comment: Got it, well if you are redoing you will have to loop through the results math with javascript, create the pagination html that way, and add on click events to them - so no html pre-written, all created as needed. Best of luck!

Comment: cool, thank you @TerraElise